# Characteristics of Zariski dense sets?

Tags: zariski-topology

What does it mean for a set to be Zariski dense? I mean what are the special that a Zariski dense set has?

Comment: The first property that comes to mind is that if a regular function $f$ is zero on a Zariski dense set $Y$ then it is zero everywhere. This is because the zero locus $V(Y)$ is a closed set containing $Y$.

Comment: $V(f)$ not $V(Y)$